# Unity and c# devkit extensions don't work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm making a game in unity using VS code with the extensions "Unity" and "C# devkit". However, today I updated unity from the 2020 version to the 2022.3.12f1 version and when I opened one of my scripts, intellisense wasn't working and some words such as functions and some variable types weren't coloured. Also, when tring to edit an arduino .cpp script the same thing happens.

I've tried a lot of things like reinstalling vs code, removing and installing extensions and updating in unity the package "visual studio editor" but none of them seem to work.